# mix of anonymous and windows authentication and force windows authentication for certain webmethods

Tags: c#, .net, windows-authentication

I set up a .NET MVC project that uses both anonymous and windows authentication to users. It is also configured enabled in IIS for those 2 authentication methods. How can we only force windows authentication and start to ask user for windows username/password for certain webmethods (calling from client side's ajax) in certain cs code for page:

```
Default.aspx
  Default.aspx.cs
```

when certain webmethod is targeted:

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public static string retr_key()
```

to pop up windows authentication request for user and once user passes that authentication, no need to ask for second time.

What needs to be done in web.config?
And what authorize attribute should be used?

Answer (score 1):

To enforce authorization on a method a `[Authorize]` attribute should be used. It can be used both on class and on a method.

When not used, the authorization is not performed. If used on a class and a method should not have authorization, an `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute can be used.

To globally specify authorization scheme (WinAuth/Forms/etc), the **web.config** file should be used.

Comment: thanks, I added `[Authorize]` attribute to the `retr_key` method however the authorize request did not trigger - after some checking, the current IIS user is 'IUSR' instead of my windows auth identity, so how to let `[Authorize]` attribute to specifically require windows auth/

Comment: Enable global authorization in application and make sure if use is not authenticated then again redirect request to login . If you want some function explicitly anonymous then add annotation allow anonymous